# Serverside Datatables Search box styling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

I have noticed that the search and show inputs for the datatables are stuck inside `<label>` tags. When I try to remove the label tags from the source JavaScript, the input disappears. I may be doing it wrong but is there a way to remove it so that I can adjust its width and make it adhere to my dynamic column sizing?

This is the part I'm talking about (from the source JavaScript file)

```
function pb(a) {
        var b = a.oClasses,
            c = a.sTableId,
            d = a.oLanguage,
            e = a.oPreviousSearch,
            f = a.aanFeatures,
            g = '<input type="search" class="' + b.sFilterInput + '"/>',
            j = d.sSearch,
            j = j.match(/_INPUT_/) ? j.replace("_INPUT_", g) : j + g,
            b = h("<div/>", {
                id: !f.f ? c + "_filter" : null,
                "class": b.sFilter
            }).append(h("<label/>").append(j)),
            f = function() {
                var b = !this.value ?
                    "" : this.value;
                b != e.sSearch && (fa(a, {
                    sSearch: b,
                    bRegex: e.bRegex,
                    bSmart: e.bSmart,
                    bCaseInsensitive: e.bCaseInsensitive
                }), a._iDisplayStart = 0, O(a))
            },
            g = null !== a.searchDelay ? a.searchDelay : "ssp" === y(a) ? 400 : 0,
            i = h("input", b).val(e.sSearch).attr("placeholder", d.sSearchPlaceholder).bind("keyup.DT search.DT input.DT paste.DT cut.DT", g ? Oa(f, g) : f).bind("keypress.DT", function(a) {
                if (13 == a.keyCode) return !1
            }).attr("aria-controls", c);
        h(a.nTable).on("search.dt.DT", function(b, c) {
            if (a === c) try {
                i[0] !== I.activeElement && i.val(e.sSearch)
            } catch (d) {}
        });
        return b[0]
    }
```

The code when the page is loaded

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div id="table_filter" class="dataTables_filter pull-left">
            <label>
                <input type="search" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Search" aria-controls="table">
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

See how the search input is under the label? I was wondering how I can remove it so that it adheres to my column sizing.

Comment: Modifying plug-in's source file is almost always a bad idea,there are other ways to do it. Can you please demonstrate with a screenshot and/or HTML what structure you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for replying. I have updated my code to show the html structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the code below to remove `label` node from the search box.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   initComplete: function(){
      $('.dataTables_filter label').children().unwrap('<label/>');
   }
});
```

See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/5udjc495/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: I'm getting a Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <label/> for some reason.

Comment: I managed to solve it based on your code! Thank you! I had to check if the parent for my specific class was a label and unwrap it.

Comment: Also, if you are the actual Gyrocode.com, thank you so much for your tutorials on checkboxes for the datatables. It was super helpful

Answer (score 0):

Although it has been so long I will answer you question for the record.

In the source file datatables.min.js, first beautify it and then you need to change the values for ssearch and ssearchplaceholder which are at line 3469.

The default is:

```
sSearch: 'Search:',
sSearchPlaceholder: "",
```

and I changed it to:

```
sSearch: '',
sSearchPlaceholder: "Αναζήτηση:",
```

Which outputs no label and "Αναζήτηση:" in the placeholder